# Easiest way to select or type over text in a text box in protractor?

Tags: protractor

In a protractor test I have an `<input type="text"/>` that is pre-filled with a value, and I'd like to erase that value and type a new one. Ideally I'd be able to just say something like

```js
// Some way to select all the text in the text box so `
// sendKeys` will type over it.
element(by.css("input.myInput")).selectAll();

element(by.css("input.myInput")).sendKeys("my new value");
```

But `selectAll` doesn't exist and I can't find anything helpful in the API docs.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I use `clear` to do this in one of my tests, works like a charm ;)

```
element(by.css("input.myInput")).clear();
```

Comment: You can also chain clear() with sendKeys() like this: `$("input.myInput").clear().sendKeys("my new value");`

Comment: Does not work for me. Here is a workaround for stubborn cases: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65477389/3021889
(eg. auto-formatted fields or protractor/OS incompatibilities)

Answer (score 11):

Found it:

```js
var ctrlA = protractor.Key.chord(protractor.Key.CONTROL, "a");
element(by.css("input.myInput")).sendKeys(ctrlA);
```

Sends Ctrl+A, the keyboard shortcut for "select all".

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work on OSX. You need Cmd+A there.

Answer (score 1):

Double click on input and click on BackSpace

`browser.actions().doubleClick(input).sendKeys(Key.BACK_SPACE).perform();`

Or double click on the input and set a new value, and it will replace previous value

`browser.actions().doubleClick(input).sendKeys('9999').perform();`

Comment: browser.actions().doubleClick(input).sendKeys('9999').perform().getText().then(function(text){console.log(text) });
I need to get text but im betting error how can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

Similar to glepretre, my solution is given the input formcontrol is named 'Name' but this worked for me

```
newValue = getNewValue();
element(by.css('input[formControlName=Name]')).clear();
element(by.css('input[formControlName=Name]')).sendKeys(newValue)
.then(function () {....});
```