# Determine Operating System/User Agent Protractor Test

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, protractor, karma-jasmine

I have a mouse/key sequence in a Protractor test that differs depending on OS (Mac vs. everything else).  I'd like to change out which key is held down durring a mouse click depending on OS or User Agent.

Depending on where I test (local Mac OSx + Chrome or headless PhantomJS on Linux) the Command key or the Ctrl key is what is needed.

Current test looks like:

```
describe('my test', function() {

  //get elements with code not shown
   ptor.actions()
                        .sendKeys(protractor.Key.CONTROL)  //mac protrator.Key.COMMAND non mac protractor.Key.CONTROL
                        .mouseDown(trs[0])
                        .mouseUp(trs[0])
                        .sendKeys(protractor.Key.NULL)
                        .perform();
                    trs[0].evaluate('selectedItems.length')
                        .then(function(count) {
                            expect(count).toBe(0);
                        })

});
```

Answer (score 3):

First a heads-up, using webdriver's *COMMAND* key [probably won't work in OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25620486/protractor-selecting-text/25628929#25628929).

Regarding a way to determine current browser OS, I use some helper functions.

#### Usage - Config file

```
onPrepare: require('./capabilities.js'),
```

#### Usage - Test files

```
if (browser.inOSX()) {
  // in Mac...
} else if (browser.inWindows()) {
  // in Windows...
} else {
  // likely in Linux...
}
```

#### Browser Capabilities Extensions

See [capabilities.js in this gist](https://gist.github.com/elgalu/4f4735f04f1eb60a70b7)