# How do I select text in protractor?

Tags: protractor

How do I select text in protractor? In my protractor test, I need to select a few words in a paragraph and click on a button on the tooltip that displays when the text is selected. How do I do this?

I found a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22241515/easiest-way-to-select-or-type-over-text-in-a-text-box-in-protractor) where the code selects all the text. I just want to select one single word.