# How do I select text in protractor to check cut module?

Tags: protractor

How do I select text in protractor? In my protractor test, I need to select a few words in a paragraph and click on a button on the tooltip that displays when the text is selected. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on your implementation. But in general you can access static tooltips by selecting HTML "title" attribute using getAttribute("title") method of the WebElement. The returned value of this method (which is the tooltip text) will be compared with an expected value for verification.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to completely emulate user's behavior I believe you need to look at [WebDriver.actions](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.actions).

The scenario should be next:

- move the mouse to the desired element using the locator
- move the mouse to the left using x,y offset
- press the mouse button down
- move the mouse to the right using x,y offset
- release the mouse button

As you can see this may be pretty raw and flaky solution so maybe you should try approach suggested by @Marius Jaraminas

Answer (score 0):

You can select all as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22241515/easiest-way-to-select-or-type-over-text-in-a-text-box-in-protractor), but non of the answers work perfectly on libux (Mac)